# Create new documents types in SharePoint

Tags: document-library, office-365

If I want to create a new document in SharePoint. The only type of document I can create is MS Word.

I want to be able to create other office document types like powerpoint, acces, excel, visio etc.

Please provide me the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add another document template:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/add-multiple-office-templates-to-a-document-library-HA102409514.aspx

Comment: I tried this link [add New templates for new document content type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-multiple-Office-templates-to-a-document-library-cde94e90-a1ba-4b94-a187-600ed68562bb?CorrelationId=12096850-dd3a-4125-959a-b15ddd8da9e5&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102409514) but im getting access denied error though i'm the admin for the tenant site office 365.Any help/

Answer (score 0):

I developed a web part that creates new Office files in web apps on any site. You can download it here - select "Free Web Part That Creates New Office Documents In Office 365 Web Apps" on this page: http://wb2-web.sharepoint.com/Pages/o365answers.aspx

If you're using Office 365, you can't create Visio etc files because 365 isn't a true cloud solution and doesn't offer the hosted software you'd need to do that. The Office web apps work by making a copy of a template, which is what this web part does for you.